# How to diferenttiate two apks installed on my phone?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been trying to install two apk's on my phone, so I getting an error when I try to install the second apk.
The first apk was installed perfectly but while I am installing the second apk get an error. I think this error is because the second project was developed
making a copy of the first one , I mean I copied the first project and I modified,renamed and created the second apk, so seems to be the second apk
is pointing or has the same configuration that the first apk. So my question is, how to diferenttiate both?, maybe on the 
project configuration there is and ID that identify. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ve done this myself. What i did was create a new Project every time before i copied the content of the original project. It worked every time. But i ve done that using android studio.

Answer (score 0):

The unique identifier of the application comes for the `package` declared in your manifest.

If you want to install the exact same copy, of two different apps, you must change the definition for one.

```
<manifest
    package="a.b.c"
    ... />
...
</manifest>
```

This however, will change the package that `R` is generated into, and may require some other import changes around the project; after changing the definition in XML, be sure to `clean` your project.